# jQuery animation starting halfway through

Tags: jquery, css

I have this css code

```
#storage_screen {
    top: -100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url(../images/new24/_landing/storage_window/container_background.png);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 99999999999999;
}
```

and this jquery code

```
$('#storage_icon').click(function() {
    $("#storage_screen").animate({top: "0"}, 600,);
});
```

but when i try it out the animation seems to start halfway through for some reason, something to do with the percentages i think.

if anyone knows of any fixes for this, i would be extremely thankful ! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you're trying to animate from a percentage value to a pixel value (0 pixels). It should work if you change the animation target to `0%` instead of just `0`.

```
$('#storage_icon').click(function() { 
    $("#storage_screen").animate({top: "0%"}, 600); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting some initial value to the top property in the css part

```
top:-200px;
```

Depending upon the height of the div, you can increase it further to -300px maybe. As I understand, you are trying to bring a div into view from top as an effect. You could also use jquery slideDown() instead. gives a similar effect.

css:

```
#storage_screen { display:none; }
```

jquery:

```
$('#storage_icon').click(function() { 
$("#storage_screen").slideDown('slow'); 
});
```